# Updating my code to store an Arraylist of checked selected items using Shared Preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm new to android development. I want to store the `selectedList` of checked items(in the `prepareSelection()`) using Shared Preferences in an `onPause()` method and restore in `onResume()`
Here's my code:

```
    public void setImageList() {
        imageRecyclerView.setLayoutManager((new  GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 4)));
        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getContext(), imageList);
        imageRecyclerView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
 
        imageAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ImageAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemViewClick(int position, View v){
                try {
                    if (!imageList.get(position).isSelected) {
                        selectImage(position);
                    } else {
                        unSelectImage(position);
                    }
                } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ed) {
                    ed.printStackTrace();
                }
 
            }
 
 
        });
    };
 
    public void selectImage(int position) {
        imageList.get(position).setSelected(true);
        imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        prepareSelection(position);
    }
 
    public void prepareSelection(int position) {
 
        if (!selectedList.contains(imageList.get(position))) {
            selectedList.add(imageList.get(position));
        } else {
            selectedList.remove(imageList.get(position));
        }
 
        
    }
 
    // Remove image from selectedImageList
    public void unSelectImage(int position) {
        imageList.get(position).setSelected(false);
        imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        prepareSelection(position);
    }
```

Comment: Store image selected list for what? Do u mean restore the selected items after kill and restart the app?

Answer (score 0):

1 use Gson translate the selectedList  to String

```
public String object2String(Object o) {
    return new Gson().toJson(o);
}
String store = object2String(selectedList)
```

2 use SharedPreferences to store the String  onPause()

3 Read the stored String  in onResume() via SharedPreferences ,and convert it to List selectedList

```
  public <T> List<T> jsonArray2Object(String jsonStr, Class<T> tClass){
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    JsonArray jsonArray = jsonParser.parse(jsonStr).getAsJsonArray();
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(JsonElement jsonElement:jsonArray){
        T t = new Gson().fromJson(jsonElement, tClass);
        list.add(t);
    }
    return list;
}

List<String> selectedList = jsonArray2Object(store ,String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save StringSet in SharedPreferences. Store the item id.

```
fun isImageSelected(id: String): Boolean {
    return getSelectedImages().contains(id)
}

fun setSelectedImages(id: String, isSelected: Boolean) {
    val newSet: MutableSet<String> = getSelectedImages()
    if (isSelected) {
        newSet.add(id)
    } else {
        newSet.remove(id)
    }
    saveStringSet("your_key", newSet)
}

private fun getSelectedImages(): MutableSet<String> {
    return preferences.getStringSet("your_key", "" ?: ""
}

@SuppressLint("ApplySharedPref")
private fun saveStringSet(key: String, stringSet: Set<String>) {
    preferences.edit().putStringSet(key, stringSet).commit()
}
```